# LDAP connection is not being established in Java

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

since I am new in **LDAP** and using spring boot security to authenticate my user from LDAP,So,I am not able to establish a successful connection and also working on hit and try method when it comes to Java code actually I need to know what should be passed in `userSearchFilter`, `userSearchBase`, `groupSearchBase`, `groupSearchFilter`, `userDnPatterns` when I have the LDAP server which is shown in the image [image: Please click here to see image].

**This is what i have tried.**

1:

```
auth.ldapAuthentication()
.userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
.userSearchBase("CN=Users,DC=test,DC=LDAP,DC=com")
.contextSource()
.url("ldap://10.10.10.1")
.port(389);
```

2:

```
auth.ldapAuthentication()
groupSearchBase("CN=Users,DC=test,DC=LDAP,DC=com")
.groupSearchFilter("sAMAccountName={0}")
.contextSource()
.url("ldap://10.10.10.1")
.port(389);
```

but each time i am getting this type of error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090724, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v23f0 ]; remaining name 'cn=Users,dc=test,dc=LDAP,dc=com'
at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:228) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:820) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeReadOnly(LdapTemplate.java:803) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntry(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:316) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch.searchForUser(FilterBasedLdapUserSearch.java:127) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator.authenticate(BindAuthenticator.java:95) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:187) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 69 common frames omitted


2017-12-04 15:28:24.501 DEBUG 10296 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090724, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v23f0 ]; remaining name 'cn=Users,dc=test,dc=LDAP,dc=com'
```

I also have tried without ***CN=Users,*** but the results are same.

Comment: Did you notice this : `[...], comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection.` ? You need to perform a successful bind before attempting to authenticate users. Settings like `binddn` and `bindpw` corresponding to a technical account with sufficient permissions should be provided for this to work.

Comment: @EricLavault, Input provided from the screen is automatically set to binddn & bindpw and this user has all the privileges i can use same user to connect from active directory explorer .

Comment: Do you know what are the defaults for all the settings you don't set explicitly ? Can you set these parameters and reflect it in your question ? Use `userDnPatterns()`, and from the `contextSource()` object you can also set `managerDn()` and `managerPassword()`, and, more importantly, call `and().passwordCompare()`. to explicitly configure the encoder (e.g. `LdapShaPasswordEncoder` and the name of the password attribute (e.g. `'userPassword'`).

Comment: Thank you it worked the problem was with `binddn` and `bindpw` i debugged it further to verify your first comment and found the problem and used `managerDn()` and `managerPassword()` to set values.